# How do I display woocommerce sales data on front end in widgets

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am wanting to know how to pull the woocommerce data from the backend to be displayed in a widget on the front-end. More specifically I am wanting to pull the data about total number of customers & the total amount of sales. This is to be used for a crowdfunding campaign page that I have built.

The total number of customers will be changed to backers & will update automatically when a sale has been processed.

The total number of customers will display the number of backers & will also  update automatically when a sale has been processed.

The idea is that all you need to build a crowdfunding single campaign site is just woocommerce & a couple of free plugins, without the need for expensive plugins that you don't need in reality.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might already know, but there are themes specially built for crowdfunding. I dont know any free plugins that can do that. The only way to get this data is to either grab them from database which will require some pretty advance mysql joins, or a better way would be to inspect the code that woocommerce uses to display the reports. Here is a great post on how to do just that http://imdev.in/woocommerce-how-to-get-total-sales-of-all-products-number/

You can use the code and create a plugin, which can then help other developers as well.

Comment: Linked site no longer exists. Please remove